# How to bind values from CSV files with a query to database?

Tags: birt

I'm trying to build a report using BIRT. I define several data sources: two CSV-files and MySQL database. A query that receives data from the database looks like this:

```
SELECT applicationType, STATUS, COUNT(*) 
FROM cards
GROUP BY applicationType, STATUS;
```

Then I created a table with three columns that outputs these values from the query:
[image]

So far so good. But I want to output values from CSV-files instead of `applicationType` and `status`. The first file, *apptype.csv*, has the following structure:

```
applicationType,apptypedescr
1,"Common Type"
2,"Type 1"
...
```

and the second one, *statuscards.csv*, has the following structure:

```
status,statuscards
1,"Blocked"
2,"Normal"
...
```

And instead of:

```
Тип приложения | Статус карты | Количество
---------------|--------------|------------
1              | 2            | 55
```

I want to output the following:

```
Тип приложения | Статус карты   | Количество
---------------|----------------|------------
Common Type    | Normal         | 55
```

I alse created `New Joint Data Set` to bind MySQL dataset and the first file dataset:

[image]

But I don't know how to change the table now. As far as I understand, `[applicationType]` in the first column should be replaced with `[apptypedescr]`:
[image]

but I'm not able to drag this field into the table, it's possible to add it to the report only outside the table. How can I bind these values from the CSV files to data from the MySQL query in the table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this by setting new dataset for table in *Properties -> Binding -> DataSet*. After this the report was built properly:

[image]